# Is there an ActiveModel validation for association consistency

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activemodel

By example:

- A `Place` belongs to a `User`.
- An `Event` belongs to a `User`.
- An `Event` belongs to (but is not required to have) a `Place`.

I'd like to validate that an `Event`'s `Place` always has the same `User` as the `Place` itself.

Validations of this form seem fairly common, yet I always end up writing my own validator. I'll include my version below for completeness, but I feel there should be a convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an `Event` *always* has the same `User` as the `Place`, perhaps you should be modelling the association like this:

```
User
  has_many :places
  has_many :events, through: :places

Place
  has_many :events
  belongs_to :user

Event
  belongs_to :place
  has_one :user, through: :place
```

Then you don't need a validation; the structure of the associations enforces that for free.

**Update**: Although `Place` is optional, I would still structure the associations like this! It sounds like you might want to break out the [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern. There are several ways you could implement it; perhaps [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) would be suitable.

Essentially, you would create a subclass `NullPlace < Place`, which would have some special behaviour (its `name` might be some placeholder like "not specified"), but in terms of the associations it would behave just like a regular `Place` so no validations required!

Comment: Unfortunately that requires that an `Event` must have a `Place`, which is not required, hence the `place.nil?` check. Good suggestion though, I've updated my question to specify this.

Comment: Sorry, I had only skimmed your answer. I've updated mine with a possible approach.

Comment: `NullPlace` is a great suggestion! And the tragedy is our system already has some *not real but actually place-holder* `Place`s! I just didn't think of extending it like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside my `Event` model:

```
validate :user_consistency

def user_consistency
  errors.add :place, 'must belong to same user as event' unless place.nil? or place.user == user
end
```